# How to implement this idea into objective fucntion with Gurobi PY

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I am working on an optimization project here and my objective is to come out with the optimal amount of each item to buy at certain vendors that can minimize the cost while meeting the demand(already figured out the demand constraints).  Here is a little background for the case below, there are 2 Vendor, 2 distribution centers(DC), 2 items(UPC), 2 Microfulfillment centers (MFC) and the chart also contain the price, weight, and cube of each items.

The freight cost of each vendor(v1, v2) is also below where v1 charges a freight fee based on the total weight and cube of all ordered items from one DC to one MFC;  v2 charges a freight fee based on the total order amount(in $) from one DC to one MFC.

Everything else for this model is done except for this complicated freight cost in the objective function.  I am stuck on this part and would really appreciate some help on how to implement this freight fee idea.  I do have an idea which is to first calculate the total the weight and cube of all ordered items from one DC to one MFC(using gp.quicksum()), then use multiple if-else statements to compare with the cube and weight range and use the corresponding freight fee.  The same idea applies to v2 where it is based on the total order amount in dollars.

Would really want some advice on whether my idea will work OR if anyone can share an easier way to implement this idea would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a decent research, I found that the tiered order amount can be implemented easily by using "Model.addGenConstrPWL()" from gurobi which is a general constraints for Piecewise function.

Below is a link for anyone that wants to take a look!

https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_agc_pwl.html

Also, another useful link is below if your piecewise function input is the sum of other variables:

https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360077610571-A-weird-output-is-it-a-bug-of-Gurobi-8-1-1-

Answer (score 1):

You may migrate this question to OR.stackechange.com where OR questions are handled.
As for the freight objective, here's the suggestion
Suppose `0 <= x[v,u,w,c]` is integer number of items `u` ordered from vendor `v` DC, of weight `w` & volume `c`
Also define some binary cost variables `v1[i]` where `i= {1,2,...6}` scenarios. Also depending upon the problem it seems vendor `v1` has created a tiered pricing based on either weight or cube volume. Every item `x` will have a weight/cube. Weight/cube is given in the table `{0.7,1.13}`& weight `{5.5,9.4}`. So you can derive the minimum numbers of items that is causing this tier system, like from freight chart for vendor `v1`, total weight=500, each weight `=5.5`, so minimum order `500/5.5`. Same for cube `999/0.7`.
Then perhaps vendor is looking at minimum of `min{500/5.5,999/0.7,500/9.4,999/1.13}`. Suppose this number is VQ[1]. Likewise you may need to recreate a table of minimum quantity of `x` for each threshold. It will be 6 scenarios with 6 freight cost `VC[i]=Cost[i]*VQ[i]`. Also `$200` at 0 weight, 0 cube, looks like setup cost which needs to be added. 
Same for vendor 2, define binary variable `v2[j]` where j=`{1,2,..5}`  scenarios. Its more straight forward, depending upon value of items ordered from DC to MFC.

Constraints:
For all `i`:
(1)   `sum(x[v1,u,w,c] over w,c,u) <= VQ[i]+Mv1[i]`
(2)   `VQ[i] <= sum(x[v1,u,w,c] over w,c,u)+M(1-v1[i])`

(3)  `sum(v1[i] over i) = 1`

Gurobi expression
`VC1 = 200 + sum(V1C[i]v1[i] over i)`: It will select one of the freight costs depending upon the volume.

For vendor 2:
for all `j`:
(4)   `sum(p[v2,d,m,u,w,c ]*x[v2,w,c,u] over w,c,u) <= V2C[j]+Mv2[j]` 
(5)  `VC[j] <= sum(p[v2,d,m,u,w,c ]*x[v2,w,c,u] over w,c,u) +M(1-v2[j])`

(6)  `sum(v2[j] over j) = 1`
`M` can be big enough number, like upper bound of `x`.

Gurobi expression
`VC2 = sum(V2C[i]v2[j] over j)`: It will select one of the freight costs depending upon the order price.

Comment: Hi Sutanu!  Thank you so so so much for your idea about posting this on the https://or.stackexchange.com/, I didn't know there is such a place before.

Comment: Let me know if this answer has been helpful.